# On the First guess nothing is being registered even if i get it right

Tags: python

This is the code:
print("Welcome to my guessing game can you get the magic number hint, it's between 1 and 100 ")

```
import random
Magic_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
print(Magic_number)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))



guess_limit = 5
guess_counter = 1
out_of_guesses = False

print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

while not out_of_guesses:
    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))

    if guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")
        exit(0)

    elif guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")

    elif guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")

    guess_counter += 1
    print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

    # exit clause
    if guess_limit == guess_counter:
        out_of_guesses = True

print("Game over, sorry")
```

And even if I get it correct on the first try it does something like this:
Welcome to my guessing game can you get the magic number
hint, 
it's between 1 and 100 
47
Enter your guess: 47
You have 4 tries left
Enter guess: 47
Well done you got it!!

As you can see even though i was correct on the first try it wasn't counted. Ps.(That is what shows up at the bottom of my screen where the code is executed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not check `if guess == Magic_number` after reading input on line 4.
Like this

```
import random
Magic_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
print(Magic_number)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))

if guess == Magic_number:
    print ("You won")
    exit(0)
```

You don't need all those variables, check this.

```
import random
Magic_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
print(Magic_number)

guess_limit = 5
guess_counter = 0

while True:
    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))

    if guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")
        exit(0)

    elif guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")

    elif guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")

    guess_counter += 1
    print(f"You have {guess_limit - guess_counter} tries left")

    if guess_counter == guess_limit:
        print("Game over, sorry")
        exit(0)
```

Comment: I credited you with the answer because some of the tweaks you mentioned fixed my issue.